# How to iterate over values with space characters?

Tags: bash

I have the following:

```
directories="directory_1 directory_2"
for k in ${directories}; do 
    echo "${k}"
done;
```

The problem is that if I add a directory with a blank space in its name, e.g. `directory 3`, this fails as it is treated as two strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an array:

```
A=(
  foo 
  "bar a" 
  blub
)

for k in "${A[@]}"; do
  echo "$k"
done
```

prints:

```
foo
bar a
blub
```

You can read more about arrays in the manual page `man bash` (search for arrays with "<kbd>/</kbd> Arrays" and use <kbd>n</kbd> to move to the next site. <kbd>h</kbd> lists more commands) or in the [Beginners Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html).